# How to change language in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to build a application in WPF/XAML that is currently in C#.
I also did not write this code, so I can not explain everything about it.

I need the code to change the language of the app to whatever the user chose in the home menu. This is the code that worked in C#:

```
public static void TranslateForm(string Language, Form f)
{
    try
    {
        string Sprachtext = string.Empty;
        clstools tools = new clstools(string.Format(string.Format(clsGlobal.CONNECTION_STRING, clsGlobal.TNSNames,
                clsGlobal.DBUser, clsGlobal.DBPassword)), clsGlobal.IDOPERATOR);

        //caption text of the form :-)
        try
        {
            if (f.Tag != null)
            {
                if (tools.IsNumeric(f.Tag.ToString()) == true)
                {
                    Sprachtext = string.Empty;

                    if (tools.GetLanguageText(Convert.ToInt32(f.Tag.ToString()), Language, ref Sprachtext) == true)
                    {
                        f.Text = Sprachtext;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ignore and proceed
        }

        foreach (Control c in f.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Tag != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Tag.ToString()) == false)
                {
                    if (tools.IsNumeric(c.Tag.ToString()) == true)
                    {
                        Sprachtext = string.Empty;

                        if (tools.GetLanguageText(Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag.ToString()), Language, ref Sprachtext) == true)
                        {
                            c.Text = Sprachtext;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //ignore
    }
}
```

If there are questions that answer this please let me know.

Also if there is anything to inprove this question please let me know.

Comment: var culture = "en-GB";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a basic example of RessourceDictionnary use, first the controller:

```
public partial class Example : Page
{
    public Example() {
        InitializeComponent();
        // In english
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add("en"));
        // In french
        //this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add("fr"));
    }
    public ResourceDictionary setLanguageDictionary(string language) {
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        switch (language) {
            case "en":
                dict.Source = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources\\StringResources.en-GB.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            case "fr":
                dict.Source = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources\\StringResources.fr-FR.xaml",
                                   UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            default:
                dict.Source = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources\\StringResources.en-GB.xaml",
                                  UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Here one of the xaml ResourceDictionary (StringResources.en-GB.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary   
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SolutionName"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="offline">Offline mode</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="login">Login</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="domain">Domain:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="username">Username:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="password">Password:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="channel">Channel</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And finally the view:

```
<Page x:Class="SolutionName.Example"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Uuniti.Vue"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Connexion1"
  xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource channel}"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I will try it tomorrow and see if it'll work.