# what i am getting the error each entry must have an associated key? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have read a lot of questions about this, but all of this questions was about VM models, and i dont have the VM model, i am trying to change the language of my application with a ResourceDictionary as is explained in this post.

[How to change language in WPF/XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855403/how-to-change-language-in-wpf-xaml)

and also i saw a lot of examples without specify any key https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-a-resourcedictionary-to-manage-localizable-string-resources

and i dont get what i am doing wrong, this is the xaml resource

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="titulo" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource Encabezado}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="tipoBase" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="imagenTitulo" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/images/asistente.jpg" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="narracion" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource tipoBase}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="botonSalirInicio" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource botonSalir}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"/>
        </Style>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Idiomas/IdiomasLogin.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Window.Resources>
```

The resource file

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ElEscribaDelDJ"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">


    <system:String x:Key="Titulo">Bienvenido a "el escriba del DJ"</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Narración">a</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="User">Usuario:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="UserText">Introduzca el nombre de usuario:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="CheckUser">Recordar Usuario:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="CheckLogin">Recordar Login:</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="License">Este producto esta bajo la licencia</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Credits">Creditos</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Other weird thing is that i cant use clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib, when i try to use it, always get an error

Properties of the ResourceDictionary
Embebed Resource
Custom tool: XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator

and lastly the textblock

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource titulo}" x:Name="titulo" Text="{DynamicResource Titulo}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put all styles into one ResourceDictionary. at the moment you have too many `<ResourceDictionary>` declarations, and the outer-most is treated as Resource but doesn't have `x:Key`, hense the error.

rewrite it like this (`<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` can be written first)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Idiomas/IdiomasLogin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>-->

        <Style x:Key="titulo" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource Encabezado}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="tipoBase" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="imagenTitulo" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/images/asistente.jpg" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="narracion" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource tipoBase}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="botonSalirInicio" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource botonSalir}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"/>
        </Style>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Idiomas/IdiomasLogin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks that solve the problem, my question now, is i should move all the styles to the resource file "IdiomasLogin.xaml" or have 2 resources in different files and combine then?

I should add something to have for example.
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>        
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
              <!--Styles  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/LoginStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Idiomas/IdiomasLogin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

Comment: @DavidPinedoSolano, resource dictionary in a separate file allows to load and reuse resources in different places (by merging that dictionary). if you use smth in one place - it doesn't have to be in separate file. if you always use two resources together - place them in the same dictionary. it is a matter of organization - similar to how we use namespaces, .NET assamblies, Nuget packages